# (.bat)According to this league of legends replay batch file, how do I correct my directory path?

Tags: batch-file

So, I have my League of Legends.exe installed in a different directory to what the .bat file indicates

the batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set VALUE_NAME=LocalRootFolder

set KEY_NAME=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Riot Games\RADS
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG.EXE QUERY "%KEY_NAME%" /v "%VALUE_NAME%" 2^>NUL ^| FIND "REG_SZ"') DO SET RADS=%%B
IF NOT "!RADS!"=="" GOTO PLAY

set KEY_NAME=HKCU\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Riot Games\RADS
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG.EXE QUERY "%KEY_NAME%" /v "%VALUE_NAME%" 2^>NUL ^| FIND "REG_SZ"') DO SET RADS=%%B
IF NOT "!RADS!"=="" GOTO PLAY

set KEY_NAME=HKCU\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Riot Games\RADS
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG.EXE QUERY "%KEY_NAME%" /v "%VALUE_NAME%" 2^>NUL ^| FIND "REG_SZ"') DO SET RADS=%%B
IF NOT "!RADS!"=="" GOTO PLAY

set KEY_NAME=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Riot Games\RADS
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG.EXE QUERY "%KEY_NAME%" /v "%VALUE_NAME%" 2^>NUL ^| FIND "REG_SZ"') DO SET RADS=%%B
IF NOT "!RADS!"=="" GOTO PLAY

GOTO NOTFOUND

:PLAY

cd /D %RADS%
cd .\solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases\
FOR /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /b') do set RELEASE=%%i
cd .\%RELEASE%\deploy

@start "" "League of Legends.exe" "8394" "LoLLauncher.exe" "-UseRads" "spectator replay.services.zam.com:80 sOeZV25yc4ycl5GiqeIdKmAtTLFIrDiu 3319341981 EUW1"
GOTO DONE

:NOTFOUND

echo Could not find League of Legends installation.
@pause

:DONE
endlocal
```

My League of Legends.exe path:

```
C:\Garena\32775\Game\League of Legends.exe
```

I'm thinking maybe I should create a shortcut at where the batch file indicates or edit the reg file that indicates the path.

But I don't really know what exactly to do, any ideas?

Comment: This batch file tries to get path to executable from Windows registry and if really found in registry, it uses `cd /D %RADS%` to set current directory to the directory read from Windows registry. From this directory it changes to subdirectory `solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases`. There it searches for one more subdirectory with obviously a variable name. After having found it, it sets current directory to subdirectory `deploy` of the release directory with variable name. Then the batch file starts `League of Legends.exe` in this directory.

Comment: Well, you don't need a batch file at all to start the application. Create a shortcut file (*.lnk) on your desktop for `League of Legends.exe`. Then right click on the shortcut and left click in context menu on last menu item to open the shortcut properties. Append to command line containing already `"C:\Garena\32775\Game\League of Legends.exe"` a space and the string `"8394" "LoLLauncher.exe" "-UseRads" "spectator replay.services.zam.com:80 sOeZV25yc4ycl5GiqeIdKmAtTLFIrDiu 3319341981 EUW1"` and close the window with __OK__. The shortcut can be used now to start the game.